# Is it possible to sort by column email and then column postcode

Tags: display, sort-order

I am runnign civicrm 5.36.1.

When I search for a list of contacts I am taken to a page listing all the contacts and fields which reflect the search parameters. I can reorder the list by clicking a column heading eg email

Can I sort how my contacts display by 2 or more column headers eg email and then postcode?

Thanks

Adding this as an EDIT because too long for comment reply: Hi Both Thanks for answering. I use groups as calling groups and do calling of contacts by selecting the first person in the list and ringing the person, filling in the answers from my script, then pressing next and going ot the next contact. I don't actually want to sort by email and postcode - I really want to sort by took multiple delivery rounds and then has ever taken a delivery round before - hence the need for two columns. It woudl enable me to call the most likely to volunteer first, then the second most likely batch and then the least likely batch without having to create separate groups. If I create a report where I can sort when I click on the first person on the list will it take me to the contact summary for the person - will I get the next button - I will give it a go anyway but any thoughts you have are appreciated. Thanks!
Caroline

Comment: sounds like Mick has given you an answer which is good, but i think i don't understand your need, since emails are mostly unique, how would it help to sort by email and then by postcode?

Comment: Hi Thanks for answering. I use groups as calling groups and do calling of contacts by selecting the first person in the list and ringing the person, filing in the answers from my script, then pressing next and going ot the next contact. I don't actually want to sort by email and postcode - I really want to sort by took multiple delivery rounds and then has ever taken a delivery round before - hence the need for two columns. PLEASE SEE FULL COMMENT ABOVE!

Comment: personally i tend to build these using Drupal Views - but depends on your CMS.

Comment: You may want to read up about the new feature called Search Kit.

Comment: More details on SearchKit here: https://civicrm.org/searchkit

Answer (score 2):

With a search (eg Find Contacts) you can only sort by a single column. But if you use a report (eg Constituent Summary) you can select the columns to display and sort by multiple columns.